# How did Jony Ive draw the curved lines along the edge of this pen so evenly spaced together?

Tags: drawing, sketching, product-design

[image]

Along the edge of the pen case there are three curved lines very close together. Was this done by hand?

Comment: Hi Jason Ginsberg, welcome to GD.SE! Not sure but he may use the same technique explained in [Before computers, how did cartographers draw roads with perfectly parallel sides?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/62086/before-computers-how-did-cartographers-draw-roads-with-perfectly-parallel-sides)

Comment: My other thought would be to use a compass and ruler.

Answer (score 6):

A quick check on Jony Ive shows that he was born in 1967, and he studied, among other things Industrial Design. While CAD was a thing in and around 1986, he most likely learned the bulk of his trade at the time using technical pens, mechanical pencils etc.

The image you provided has all the hallmarks of technical drawing, but also looks to be worked up with some mechanical typefaces. My guess is that this image is a combination of hand techniques and computer-driven techniques, but there is no reason he could not have worked that up by hand.

I took a class called "Drafting" for a year in high school (7th or 8th grade) and it is taught quite rigidly so as to have all students conform to a standard which includes learning how to write letters and numbers all over again. There is very little free-hand line drawing involved (none really): you must use t-squares, triangles, compass, compound curve tools (the pink things in the photo below) etc.:

[image]

When you are making drawings that can be used make the actual parts, the measurements matter and your accuracy must be good.

Comment: I think this is a pretty good theory. It has all the halmarks of a marker rendering, but that is so easily replicated with digital tools these days that this may very well have been done digitally at least to some extent.

Comment: In addition to, say, using a compass with carefully-measured radii, there were also roller sleeves you could use on a mechanical pencil or Rapidograph-style pen that would let you get even offsets from French curves and other stencilly thingamabobs. And for the writing-impaired, there were lettering tools like the Rotring controlled lettering kit - a pain in the butt to use, admittedly, but easier than the half-stencils where you needed to fill in the inevitable blanks.